# How can I pass several inputs' values into bound function?

Tags: binding, knockout.js

If I have:

```
  ...
    <li>Title: <input id="name" /></li>
    <li>Author: <input id="author" /></li>
  ...
```

`<button data-bind='click: $root.Add'>Add</button>`

and I wanted to pass in the user input to a function (`Add`) bound to a button, how would I accomplish this?

I don't know how to pull the values and then pass them as parameters.

Comment: Is this binding happening inside a foreach binding?

Comment: @PatrickSteele no, it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind your method call to use the viewmodel ($root) as the "this" context for your method.  Then just access the properties as you normally would:

http://jsfiddle.net/psteele/Wf9xj/

```
<div>Title: <input id="name" data-bind="value: name" /></div>
<div>Author: <input id="author" data-bind="value: author" />
    <input type="button" value="X" data-bind="click: show.bind($root)"></input></div>

var vm = {
    name: 'Bob',
    author: 'King',
    show: function() {
        alert(this.name + '-' + this.author);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Okay, so basically the inputs have to also be bound to really handle this then.

Comment: Correct.  Once they're bound, this becomes very easy.